# cocos2d wheel spinning like wheel of fortune

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm developing spinning wheel app with cocos2d.
the wheel will be seen from top view.
I can spin the wheel (only one sprite) & stop the spinning wheel.

```
wheel = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"wheel500.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)]; 
id spin = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:.5 angle: 360];
id spins = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:spin times:8];
[wheel runAction:spins];
```

The wheel has 6 or 8 segments. I want to add text in all segment (dynamically).
Thanks for any hints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add all the text to the wheel.. Means the text is now child of wheel.. den you are done.. what ever the parent(wheel) does, the child(text) will follow..